# C sscanf Need help understanding

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to learn some C I think it is?
I'm looking at the following code for sscanf

```
sscanf(val1,":%[^ ] %s %s %[^\n]%*[\n\r]%n", val2 , val3 , val4 , val5 ,&n);
```

But I'm having a lot of trouble understanding it, I've looked online about sscanf, and from what I understand the char array in val1 gets chopped up into val2, val3, val4, val5 and &n. But I don't quite understand this bit:

```
:%[^ ] %s %s %[^\n]%*[\n\r]%n
```

I'm assuming the string gets chopped up based on the %s, parts but the rest I'm not too sure, I was really hoping someone might be able to give me say an example string, and how that turns into the different values?
Thanks!!

Comment: RTFM. The documentation for `scanf` explains what the `[` specifier does.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html Cannot be much plainer than that man-page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format string is parsed as follows:

```
:%[^ ] %s %s %[^\n]%*[\n\r]%n
^  ^    ^ ^     ^   ^   ^   ^
|  |    | |     |   |   |   |
|  |    | |     |   |   |   +-- the number of characters read so far
|  |    | |     |   |   +------ \n or \r
|  |    | |     |   +---------- read and ignore this portion of the input
|  |    | |     +-------------- Read string up to \n; should be [^\n\r]
|  |    | +-------------------- Read a string
|  |    +---------------------- Read a string
|  +--------------------------- Read a string up to a space character
+------------------------------ Read a ':' character
```

Single spaces, where present, indicate that a sequence of zero or more space characters needs to be consumed, and not be placed into any of the output variables. For example, `"%s %s"` applied to `"hello       world"` string would place `"hello"` into the first string, and `"world"` into the second string, and ignore the spaces separating these two strings.

The `%n` format is there so that you could tell how many characters have been consumed from the input by this operation. This is commonly done to adjust the position for the next read in the loop, and determining if the loop should continue or terminate.

Note: using `%s` is unsafe, because entering a sufficiently long sequence of characters would result in buffer overruns. When you read a string into a buffer of length `N`, you should put the size of `N-1` between `%` and `s`. For example, if you read the strings into buffers of size 32, change your format string as follows:

```
:%31[^ ] %31s %31s %31[^\n]%*[\n\r]%n
```

This ensures that there is no buffer overrun when the user enters more than 31 characters. Character 32 needs to be reserved for the null terminator.

Comment: "a space character needs to appear in the string at that point" That doesn't cut it. That an **optional** unlimited sequence of whitespace-characters will be matched.

Comment: A space in the pattern can match an empty sequence too.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about this one "a string up to a space character" does that mean that it will take a string value of everything up to the next space ' '? Thanks for your answer, super helpful, and easily understandable.

Comment: @JohnMcKenzie Yes, the first format specifier will take input up to the first space, which will be excluded.